# Select union all cursor

Tags: mysql, loops, cursor

I have the following tables

```
tab_1: 

(rs)
rs1
rs2
rs3

tab_2: 

(rs) (cell) (tf)
rs1  A549    tf1
rs1  C555    tf2
rs3  B333    tf1
```

I need to loop on the tab_1 only column and check:

```
SELECT count(distinct cell) from tab_2 where rs = 'rs1'
union all
SELECT count(distinct cell) from tab_2 where rs = 'rs2'
union all
SELECT count(distinct cell) from tab_2 where rs = 'rs3';
```

and get the result

```
2
0
1
```

Can't understand how Cursor should work or just a simple loop(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include the zero count for `rs2`, which is in `tab_1` but not `tab_2`, you need a `LEFT JOIN`

Also, you don't need to `UNION` for each value - a basic `GROUP BY` will do the trick:

```
SELECT tab_1.rs, COUNT(DISTINCT tab_2.cell)
FROM tab_1
LEFT JOIN tab_2 ON tab_1.rs = tab_2.rs
GROUP BY tab_1.rs
ORDER BY tab_1.rs
```

Using your sample data, the result of this query is:

```
rs1   2
rs2   0
rs3   1
```

There's a SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/475a6/1).